# Details Of How SOAP Requests Are Sent Over HTTP

Tags: web-services, http, soap

Please I'll like to know how SOAP requests are sent over HTTP POST. Is the entire envelope posted raw into the request body such as can be read entirely into a String with the following method call?

`String entireSoapReequest = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream());`

Additional details would also be appreciated

Comment: Use a program like [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to observe what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. All the soap requests are post requests, and behave exactly as simple http post requests.